# Possible to process non-thread-safe code in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a C# program that performs a `foreach` on `DataRows`. The simplified version is:

```
foreach (DataRow row in masterReportData.Rows)
{
    LoopThruReports(row, p2, p3, p4);
}
```

And `LoopThruReports` is declared as:

```
public static void LoopThruReports(DataRow row, DataTable p2, string p3, string p4)
```

I'd really like to have the iterations run in parallel because they fill a `SqlDataAdapter` from a database (which takes a while). Despite trying threads, tasks, and the parallel library, I cannot figure out if this is even possible to do. If only I could have each thread not share variables with other threads! Does anyone have any ideas on whether this is possible, and if so, how I could do it? Thanks.

EDIT: The `LoopThruReports` method calls `GetGCHAReportDetailData`, which is where the `Fill` is done. Here's what this method looks like:

```
    public static DataSet GetGCHAReportDetailData(int reinsuranceContract, int billingMode, DateTime reportPeriod)
    {
        DataSet dsResults = new DataSet();
        DataTable gchaReportData = new DataTable();

        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UtopiaConnString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.[sproc_GCHADetailDataForContract]"))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //set the command time out to 60 minutes b/c this report takes time to generate
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@ReinsuranceContractId", SqlDbType.Int);
            parm.Value = reinsuranceContract;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

            SqlParameter parm1 = new SqlParameter("@BillingMode", SqlDbType.Int);
            parm1.Value = billingMode;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);

            SqlParameter parm2 = new SqlParameter("@ReportingPeriod", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            parm2.Value = reportPeriod;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parm2);
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                sqlCmd.Connection = conn;

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(dsResults);

                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Error(ex, "Error retrieving data from the database.\r\n Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                            conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dsResults;
    }
```

Comment: Whether this is possible or not depends on your implementation and the tables you're updating. You need to show us your code in order for us to help you.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thanks. The class is hundreds of lines long. What code do you want to see?

Comment: So is the cost of execution ***specifically*** in filling the adapter, or is it in the computation of the values that fill the adapter?

Comment: You will probably just need some synchronization in `LoopThruReports` to make sure that any writes happen atomically. Reading data and calculating on it will *probably* be safe, but it's hard to guarantee anything without seeing code.

Comment: The cost of execution is the `Fill` of the DataAdapter

Comment: I don't see the `Fill` being called anywhere in your example, where does it happen?

Comment: `Fill` is used to fill a dataset with data through an adapter from a sql server.  There is no way to make that multi threaded as the bottle-neck is either the sql server, or the network connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to multi-thread multiple `Fill` calls to the same SQL server will be a loosing battle.  Both he SQL server and the network are already sending you data as fast as they can.  By splitting the `Fill` calls over multiple threads you are actually going to slow things down.  The bandwidth will be split equally between each thread (so there will be no performance increase), except each thread will also incur some overhead, which will slow things down a bit.  Each thread you add will compound this problem more.

If each `Fill` runs against a different database then you *might* be able to get some threading improvement, as they won't be competing for the same SQL resources, though network contention will still be an issue.

I don't see anything in your code that would make multi-threading unsafe, I just don't see how threading it will improve your processing time.

---

Comments indicate that you are actually generating reports from the data, and that is what you want to multi-thread.  This may actually work.  As long as the reports only read data, and never write data, you should be able to thread them, and share a single dataset.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), `DataTables` and `DataSet` have this note "This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations."

It should be perfectly fine to share the same `DataSet` instance between threads as long as you only  **read** from it, **writing** will require special handling.

Comment: This program generates reports based on the data that comes back from the sproc. Each iteration of the `foreach` results in a new (separate) report. When I do multi-thread the iterations it finishes much faster because the reports are being generated in parallel. The problem is, all of the reports are the same (presumably because they're all sharing the same data returned by the sproc). Wouldn't I be good if only the returned dataset wasn't being shared?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelDBProcessing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                int temp = i;
                Task task = Task.Run(() => DoWork(temp));   // use Task.Run if you want to get task.Result back
                taskList.Add(task);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        }

        public static void DoWork(int num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            string connstr = @"Data Source = (local)\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = Barry; Integrated Security = true";

            DataSet dsResults = new DataSet();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.[spMagicProc]"))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@Input_A", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm.Value = num;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

                SqlParameter parm1 = new SqlParameter("@Input_B", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm1.Value = 2;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    sqlCmd.Connection = conn;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            da.Fill(dsResults);
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                                conn.Close();
                        }
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine(dsResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```